# NullPointerException testing ADS method

Tags: java, testing

I'm fairly new to java and I'm trying to test some of my methods in a class but I got the NullPointerException

```
public class ArrayListTest {

private List ar;

@org.junit.Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    List ar = new ArrayList();
}

@Test
public void testAdd() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(ar);
    ***ar.add(33);***
```

The error points at ar.add(33);

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.company.ArrayListTest.testAdd(ArrayListTest.java:23)
...a bunch of other invokes...
```

Looking into add method, I can't find anything wrong.

```
public class ArrayList implements List{

private Object[] elems;

private int nrElems;

public ArrayList() {
    nrElems = 0;
    elems = new Object[10];
}

public void add(Object e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    if (nrElems == elems.length) {
        resize();
    }
    elems[nrElems++] = e;
}
```

Any ideas? The test class is using my own implementation of ArrayList

Comment: Is this your own implementation of `ArrayList` ?

Comment: Yea. It's just some basic thing. The problem must be in the add method cause that's what is causing the problems

Comment: Does your code work with java util `ArrayList` ?

Comment: My test works with my own implementation of ArrayList.

Comment: Your test obviously doesn't work properly if it gives you a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that out myself. The error in the test points to ar.add(33). How can calling a method throw NullPointerException? It must be something in the add method, no? But what is it?

Comment: You might want to do some research about _shadowing_. After you've done that, you can fix your problem without further help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, post the actual code and console text.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll edit and pos the code. Also at @Tom I don't see where my shadowing occurs?

Comment: Your exception occurs in your test class, so how about looking there?

Comment: In your `setUp()` method, change line `List ar = new ArrayList();` to `ar = new ArrayList();`.

Comment: Ok, I removed the private List ar and the initialization in the setUp and did the initialization in testadd and it works fine. It makes no sense to me. I followed a youtube guide to using the "setUp" from JUnit4 and it worked for them.

Comment: So can I assume you didn't do any research about "shadowing"? You would understand your problem in your posted code, if you would do that.

Comment: Oooh I see now. I put List every time, should've only put it once. Thank you!

Comment: @dguay thank you too, only now I saw your commentxD after I did some research on shadowing

Comment: *"after I did some research on shadowing"* Good to hear :). If you now know what it is, then it is easier for you to avoid such problems in the future.

Comment: True that, it will certainly help me in my future coding ^^